# Como processar JSON que possui um array de objetos como propriedade com Observable (AngularJS)?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

Possuo uma API que retorna os objetos `JSON` da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "nome": "objeto1"
        },
        {
            "nome": "objeto2"
        },
    ]
}
```

Porém, ao receber os objetos no `service`, eu não consigo pegar apenas os objetos, e me retorna um objeto que tem como propriedade uma variável `data` array de objetos, o que é extremamente confuso e difícil de lidar.

Ao dar um `console.log` no objeto recebido, me veio o seguinte retorno:

```
{data: Array(2)}
```

`Service` (**detalhe**: tive que mudar o tipo de retorno em todos os lugares onde aparece `Objeto` para `any`):

```
const JSON_PATH = environment.path;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContaCorrenteService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

  public listAll():Observable<Objeto[]>{
    return this.http.get<Objeto[]>(BANK_ACCOUNT_PATH);
    }
}
```

Objeto esperado:

```
export interface Objeto{
    nome: string;
    /* demais propriedades */
}
```

Em resumo: como converter aquele objeto recebido na chamada do HttpClient para array (para que, ao invés de eu passar o objeto como `objetos.data` no `foreach`, passar apenas como `objetos`)?

Comment: Não ficou nem um pouco clara sua pergunta, está utilizando qual Angular? No código parece ser o Angular mas na pergunta colocou Angularjs, e o que pretende fazer com o retorno da Api?

Comment: Angular 8 (me confundi na escrita das tags). Pretendo apenas converter o retorno para um `array` de objetos antes de realizar o subscribe nos componentes que utilizarem o `service`, ao invés do objeto com `array` que estou recebendo

Comment: O que aparece quando vc faz isso: `console.log(JSON.stringify(objeto), null, ' ', false)` ?

Comment: {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Ms. Bert Denesik"},{"id":2,"name":"Mstgopaijdqoruehjgpza"}]} null   false

Comment: A API é sua? Se sim, bota ela pra imprimir o resultado sem o data. Ou então cria um objeto para manipular resultados da API com o campo 'data' e array any[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export interface Objeto{
    nome: string;
    /* demais propriedades */
}

export interface ObjetoPayload {
 data: Objeto[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContaCorrenteService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

  public listAll():Observable<Objeto[]>{
    return this.http.get<ObjetoPayload>(BANK_ACCOUNT_PATH).pipe(map((res: ObjetoPayload) => res.data));
    }
}
```

Se você quer pegar apenas a data, isso resolve o seu problema.